# Not able to set label text from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Requirement is to set the label text from the tree view when user select any node. While debugging I am getting hospitalName correctly but it is not setting label text.

```
$("[id$=HospitalTreeViewDiv] span").click(function () {

  var hospitalName = $(this)[0].outerText;

  //this is also not working
  // $("label[for='SelectedHospitalLiteral']").text(hospitalName); 

  $("[id$=SelectedHospitalLiteral]").val("abc");

});
```

This is aspx snippet

```
   <div runat="server" id="HospitalTreeViewDiv">
            <asp:TreeView ID="HospitalTreeView" runat="server" ExpandDepth="0">
            </asp:TreeView>
   </div>

   <div class="alignBottom">
        <p> <asp:Label ID="SelectedHospitalLiteral" runat="server" ></asp:Label></p>
   </div>
```

Comment: for `<label>` its `.text("your text")`

Comment: Please end the statements with `;`

Comment: `.val()` is used just for elements that have `value`, which is not the case for the `label`. Use `.text()` or `.html()` instead.

Comment: correcting `;` doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HiddenField for Postbacks

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="labelText" Value=""/>

$("[id$=HospitalTreeViewDiv] span").click(function () {
      $("[id$=labelText]").val("abc")
});
```

refer to this: [How to change the text of a label in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584145/change-text-of-label-in-jquery)

Comment: short time smile... `$html` worked at UI but at code behind still I am getting old values

Comment: what do you mean by code behind: once you set the text for label, you will be able to access that value in code behind...#

Comment: No, I checked that $html is changing the text but when you see label.Text code behind it will give the old value (in my case it was empty) so I am getting this rendered html
`<p><span id="ctl00_Content_SelectedHospitalLiteral"/>
<p>
...`

Comment: are you posting back your page, or is it redirected to same page. because when you want to access the text in code-behind, if it is not posted back it will re-render the HTML and re-set the text of label

Comment: I am new to asp.net, let me analyze your last comment

Comment: I think it is yes, its PoastBack... setting the label text is happening on popup screen and on popup screen "Ok" button code behind i am checking labels last updated value...

Any other idea!

Comment: why dont you use asp:HiddenField rather than changing label value. hiddenfield values will be persisted during postbacks..

Comment: Great suggestion... hidden field can work for me. Please edit your answer and suggest for hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `asp controls label control` use `ClientID` to get the control:

Also to set text use `text("yourtext")`

Working with your code here:

```
 $("[id$=HospitalTreeViewDiv] span").click(function () {

      var hospitalName = $(this)[0].outerText; //your forgot to give semicolon here

      $("#<%=SelectedHospitalLiteral.ClientID%>").text("abc"); // and also semicolon  here 

    });
```

Comment: in my case it crashed `$("#<%=HospitalTreeViewDiv.ClientID%>").` itself.. it says
`Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%= HospitalTreeViewDiv.ClientID %>`

Comment: yes ur r right it will crash.Render ids will be multiple so...modified ans