# Replacing a label's text if there's a nested input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, label

Changing the text of a label seems [easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584145):

```js
var /**HTMLLabelElement*/ label = ...;
label.innerHTML = "...";
```

or, using *jQuery*:

```js
var /**HTMLLabelElement*/ label = ...;
$(label).text("...");
```

Neither of the above works correctly if the label wraps the `<input/>` element:

```html
<label><input type="checkbox">Text</label>
```

-- in this case, the `<input/>` element is replaced along with the old text.

How do I change just the text of a label, without affecting its child elements?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Filter out the non-empty text child nodes and replace it with the new content.

```js
$('label')
  // get all child nodes including text and comment
  .contents()
  // iterate and filter out elements
  .filter(function() {
    // check node is text and non-empty
    return this.nodeType === 3 && this.textContent.trim().length;
    // replace it with new text
  }).replaceWith('new text');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">Text</label>
```

---

Pure JavaScript method

```js
var label = document.querySelector('label');

// get all child nodes and update the text node from it
label.childNodes[2].textContent = 'new text'
// If you don't know the position 
// then iterate over them and update
// based on the node type
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">Text</label>
```

Comment: Very cool. For more reference, see [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType).

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) property to selecting sibling text of input.

```js
document.querySelector('input').nextSibling.nodeValue = "newText";
```

```html
<label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    Text
</label>
```