# MVC How to display total amount automatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Im trying to display the total amount in MVC from @Html.TextboxFor()s to @Html.DisplayFor() without total buttons or anything. Just like in winform textChange but I don't have any idea how to do it.

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.num1)
 @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.num2)
```

while changing the amount in textboxes, the displayfor will automatically diplays the total

I added this based on Linoy's answer but the .text doesn't seem to display the result.

```
        $('.getNum1').blur(function () {
            var val1 = $(this).val();
            var val2 = $('.getNum2').val();

            $('.gettotal').text(parseInt(val1) + parseInt(val2));
        });
```

Comment: You need to use javascript to respond to client side events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the steps you can make a try

step1: Add class names to two txtboxes and label(we can easily select the textbox with jquery)

Step2: use jquery "onblur" event to identify text box changes(use onblur event in both txtboxes)

Step3: inside the event callback, check all the text boxes are filled. You can fetch textbox values with below query
$('.txtboxclassname').val()

Step4: do your logic and update the result to label

$('.labelclassname').text(yourresult)

[How to change the text of a label in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584145/how-to-change-the-text-of-a-label-in-jquery)

Comment: thank you .blur is working fine but step4 is not displaying the result

Comment: Could you just console the result and check you parsed the values correctly.   like console.log(val1+val2)

Comment: i tried console.log and it perfectly displays the answer

Comment: Okay, Can you try 
$('.gettotal').innerHTML =yourresult

Comment: @Amits, Just now I tried $('.labelclassname').text("some text") and it updated correctly. so I strongly believe your selection is wrong.
Place $('.gettotal') in browser developer console and see you selected label correctly.

Comment: Could you paste the response of $('.gettotal') from browser developer console.

Comment: [object Object] is displays this

Comment: Hmm. Please paste your label html here. I have to take a look

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.proposalsTbl.Saving.January, new{@class="getNum1"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.proposalsTbl.Saving.February, new{@class="getNum2"})

@Html.DisplayFor(s=>s.Tamount,new { @class="gettotal"})

Comment: DisplayFor returns HTML elements based on the property type. I believe in your html instead of label a textbox is created. so for textbox syntax is different.

$('.gettotal').val(yourresult)

Comment: Nice to know @Amits

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.num1, new { @class = "prop" })
     @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.num2, new { @class = "prop" })

    <span class="gettotal"></span>

         $(".prop").on("input", function (e) {
                           // debugger;
                            var total = 0;
                            $('input[class*="prop"').each(function () {
                                var rowval = $(this).val();
                                total = total + parseInt(rowval);
                            });
                            $('.gettotal').text(total);
                        });
```